# Make ViewPager overlap PageTitleStrip

Tags: android, android-viewpager, page-title

I've been struggling with that for a while: Is it possible to force PageTitleStrip draw itself on the content of the ViewPager?

Here is the case: [image: screen]

The red line indicates the end of ViewPager content and the start of PagerTitleStrip. The brown background belongs to the hole activity. Blackboard and blue backgrounds are from fragments in pager. The screen is taken during scrolling so that 2 fragments can be seen. I want the icons from PagerTitleStrip to be displayed transaprently and party on the viewPager's content.

Any suggestions are highly appreciated.

Comment: I am struggling to find out what you want, is thins something like market app?

Comment: Nixit, sorry I don't get your feedback. You don't understand my question, right? If yes I could try to be more precise. It's just an app I develop in my freetime

Comment: I don't see any easy way to do this, you have to modify the source of already available ViewPager Library, Its achievable, but it will be trick

Comment: can you add some graphical representation on things what you want, so any one can easily understand what you want

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible to do this with the built-in ViewPager and PagerTitleStrip.  You will have to make your own custom component based on these to get the effect you're looking for.